# `Jtree` and `TreeModel`: is order of `getChildCount` and `getChild` guaranteed?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

Is it safe to assume that `TreeModel.getChild` is always called **for the last** parent checked by `getChildCount`?
In other words, `JTree` doesn't cache number of children, and the order is always the following:

```
getChildCount(Foo)
getChild(Foo, 1)
getChild(Foo, 2)

getChildCount(Bar)
getChild(Bar, 1)
getChild(Bar, 2)
```

..and never

```
getChildCount(Foo)
getChildCount(Bar)
getChild(Foo, 1)
getChild(Foo, 2)
getChild(Bar, 1)
getChild(Bar, 2)
```

My model wraps thing that provides a list of a children. Unfortunately, each call might return different list.
I want to cache the last result i.e (code isn't real of course)

```
getChildCount(parent) {
  this.parent = parent
  this.children = foo.getList(parent)
  return this.children.size()
}
//
getChild(parent, index) {
  assert(this.parent == parent)
  return children[index]
}
```

Or is it completely wrong, and `JTree` is free to cache anything and I should explicitly notify `TreeModelListener` about any change?

Comment: If you’re asking about guarantees as to when methods of TreeModel are called, the answer is that there are no guarantees.  If your TreeModel’s data changes, or the data’s order changes, the model must notify its listeners of this.  It cannot change the order when model methods are called.  Your TreeModel will have to enforce a consistent order.

Comment: The first misconception is the assumption that only `JTree` can call methods on the tree model. The [model is exposed](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTree.html#getModel()) and can be accessed from arbitrary places, be it application code or Look&Feel specific artifacts. Besides that, there is no need to think of caching to get to the conclusion that a component where the *user* decides when to expand nodes may access children in arbitrary order. In fact, the second scenario is actually more likely than the first for most nodes.